# I need to create a web app which need push notification without FCM/GCM or APN

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, endpoint, push-api

I need to send push notification even the site is closed, So I've tried service worker and web worker even web socket but it didn't works fine. It need FCM(Firebase Cloud messaging) to transfer payload from server
,but my server don't support Nodejs so I can't use Firebase

I need a solution to create a custom endpoint to delivery payload to a client in the Background. So, I can push a notification from the Service worker instantly even the site is closed

Comment: You need to use the Push API and it relies on the browser push service. There aren't any other ways to deliver notifications when the website is closed.

Comment: How to tigger push when new message created, from push api . and I can't understand how to get payload from my SQL Server